# Spring webFlow bind a list of objects with checkboxes

Tags: spring, type-conversion, spring-webflow, type-mismatch

I'm trying to create a list of checkboxes for a list of objects.
In my form backing bean I have 2 lists. One list with the reference data that contains all my organizations. Another list that will contain the selected organizations.

My page loads fine but when I try to submit it I get the following exception:

```
 Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'typeMismatch on selectedOrganizations' for locale 'nl'.
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:852)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:781)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.flows.validation_jsp._jspService(validation_jsp.java:177)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:480)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.wizard_tag._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(wizard_tag.java:198)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.wizard_tag.doTag(wizard_tag.java:146)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.management.roleinvitation.create.selectOrganizations_jsp._jspx_meth_iam_005fwizard_005f0(selectOrganizations_jsp.java:375)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.management.roleinvitation.create.selectOrganizations_jsp._jspService(selectOrganizations_jsp.java:141)
    ... 126 more
```

Find my code snippets here:

**JSP**

```
<c:forEach items="${organizations}" var="${organization}">
  <form:checkbox cssClass="organizationCheckbox" path="selectedOrganizations" value="${organization}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

**View Model**

```
public class CreateRoleInvitationViewModel implements Serializable {
  private List<OrganizationViewModel> selectedOrganizations;
  private List<OrganizationViewModel> organizations;
...
}
```

**Converter**

```
public class StringToOrganizationViewModel extends StringToObject {

  public StringToOrganizationViewModel() {
    super(OrganizationViewModel.class);
  }

  @Override
  protected Object toObject(String code, Class targetClass) throws Exception {
    OrganizationViewModel orgViewModel = new OrganizationViewModel();
    orgViewModel.setCode(code);
    return orgViewModel;
  }

  @Override
  protected String toString(Object object) throws Exception {
    return ((OrganizationViewModel)object).getCode();
  }

}
```

I've checked if the converter is used and it is used. I pass the toString(Object object) method when my page gets loaded.
When I try to submit I don't pass the toObject(String code, Object objectClass) because the exception occurs before it.

**Note**: When I only select one checkbox..everything works fine. I can see that my backing bean contains a selectedOrganisations list with one entry. When I select multiple checkboxes than it crashes....

Answer (score 1):

in your jsp, in the forEach tag you made a little mistake, it should be `var="organization"` instead of `var="${organization}"`